# numpy.gradient with edge_order=2

Tags: python, numpy

I don't understand the fontionnement of the option edge_order=2 of np.gradient :

```
x=np.arange(5)**2
print(x)
print(np.gradient(x,edge_order=2))
```

np.gradient return :

```
[0. 2. 4. 6. 8.]
```

I don't understand why value at index 0 is 0 and not : (x[1]-x[-1])/2=(1-16)/2=-7.5

And at index 4 it's 8 and not : (x[0]-x[3])/2=(0-6)/2=-3

Comment: Explain your expected values.

Comment: It is the formula for second order differences : (x[i+1]-x[i-1])/2 on the edges.

Comment: `[7.5. 2. 4. 6. -3]` gradient does not look right, by any edge handling mode.  0 and 8 are consistent with the interior gradient values.  The first edge should be based, at most on the first 3 values  [0,1,4].  Likewise the last on the last 3 [4,9,16].  Using `x[1] and `x[4]` to get the first edge is rediculous.

Comment: Thanks, I believed that this argument is for perodical bonds conditions.